Normally distributed R.V. depends only on numeric parameters.
Random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent and have normal distribution with $0$ mean and $1$ variance. prove that distribution of r.v. $Z = (X+a)^2 + (Y+b)^2$ depends only from $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, i.e. if we fix $r > 0$ then it will be the same for all $a, b:a^2+b^2=r^2$
I'm thinking about geometric solution because it definitely looks like a circle, but I can't come up with the following solution (or with another, non-geometric solution)...
Any help would be appreciated!

Claim: The distribution of
$$Z := (X-a)^2+(Y-b)^2$$
only depends on $a,b>0$ via $r:=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}>0.$
Proof. Let us interpret the claim in terms of planar geometry. We write $(x,y)$ for a point in the plane $\mathbb R^2,$ and $\lVert (x,y) \rVert:=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for its distance from the origin. Suppose that $a',b'>0$ satisfies $r=\sqrt{a'^2+b'^2},$ i.e. both $(a, b)$ and $(a', b')$ lie on the circle centered at the origin with radius $r$. Let $O$ denote the rotation  in the plane that maps $(a, b)$ to $(a', b')$.
Recall that a standard bivariate Gaussian random variable is rotationally invariant, i.e. for any rotation $R$ both $(X, Y)$ and $R(X,Y)$ have the same distribution. Then
$$Z=\lVert (X, Y)-(a,b) \rVert^2=\lVert O((X, Y)-(a,b)) \rVert^2=\lVert O(X, Y)-(a',b') \rVert^2 =_d \lVert (X, Y)-(a',b') \rVert^2,$$
where $=_d$ denotes equality in distribution, and we obtain the claim.
